# Pycharm debugger console not autocompleting variables created in the debugger console

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, console, code-completion

I have just upgraded to PyCharm 2023.3.3 community edition and am experiencing a weird issue that hasn't occurred before. System is Windows 10 64 bit, and this has worked fine on this machine before.

When I debug a script and hit a breakpoint and the program is suspended and the debugger window is opened, autocomplete doesn't seem to work on new variables i create in the debugging console, however it works on variables created in the script before the breakpoint was hit.

**e.g., Script**

[image: Script and breakpoint]

**Debugging console showing autocomplete working for variable *testing* but not *test***

[image]

Any ideas why the debugging console is not autocompleting *test*? and how I could fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open **Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console** and switch **Code Completion** to *Runtime*. Relevant ticket in PyCharm's issue tracker - [PY-64055](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-64055/Completion-doesnt-work-in-Debug-Console).

Comment: Thanks Pavel, however now that I have done this, code completion isn't automatically suggested as i type. I have to ctrl+ spacebar, or tab to manually bring up the autocomplete context menu. Is there a work around for this side effect as well?

Comment: @Sighonide Unfortunately, there is no workaround I am familiar with. That's an old issue with "Runtime" completion in the console - [PY-18609](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18609).

Comment: Thanks, that was driving me crazy, had the same issue with the pro version. Shouldn't the behavior be made consistent with the  previous configuration when updating to 2023.3.3 ?